# Why can't unprivileged users nest FUSE mounts, but they can mount FUSE inside NFS with root_squash?

Tags: nfs, fuse, setuid

```
$ mkdir mnt

$ bindfs /tmp mnt
fusermount: option allow_other only allowed if 'user_allow_other' is set in /etc/fuse.conf

$ bindfs --no-allow-other /tmp mnt

$ mkdir /tmp/mnt2
$ bindfs --no-allow-other /tmp mnt/mnt2
fusermount: bad mount point /home/alan/mnt/mnt2: Permission denied
```

`fusermount` fails because it runs as a different user.

```
$ sudo ls mnt/
ls: cannot open directory 'mnt/': Permission denied
```

`fusermount` is set-uid `root`.  This is required because unprivileged users cannot use the `mount()` system call.

```
$ ls -l $(which fusermount)
-rwsr-xr-x. 1 root root 32848 Feb  7  2018 /usr/bin/fusermount

   ^ set-uid bit
```

And yet.  It is reported that FUSE can be used inside an NFS home directory.  Even though the home directory has mode `700` - accessible only by the owning user.  And the NFS server defaults to `root_squash`, which means "the root user will have the same access as user nobody".

Why do these two cases differ?

I am testing on Fedora 28.  The reports about NFS are from Ubuntu 18.04.  These distributions are quite similar in age, but there might be some differences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, consider the implementation of FUSE `no_allow_others`.

It requires that the effective, real, and saved UIDs (user IDs) all match.  (And the same for GID).  This is deliberately to stop a set-UID program from accessing the mount.

https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v4.18/fs/fuse/dir.c#L1024

> Calling into a user-controlled filesystem gives the filesystem
>   daemon ptrace-like capabilities over the current process.  This
>   means, that the filesystem daemon is able to record the exact
>   filesystem operations performed, and can also control the behavior
>   of the requester process in otherwise impossible ways.  For example
>   it can delay the operation for arbitrary length of time allowing
>   DoS against the requester.

Now let's trace what `fusermount` does.  We can try looking at

```
strace -f bindfs ...
```

and

```
sudo perf trace -o trace.txt -a sleep 2; sleep 1; bindfs ...
```

The first one hits a fatal error "Permission denied", because set-UID root does not work when running under `strace`.  The second one succeeds, but cannot show string parameters such as paths.  I think the two traces show the same general code path up until the fatal error.  This means we can use the `strace` results to fill in the missing string parameters.

That last call in the `strace` results is:

```
[pid 30609] mount("/home/alan-sysop/mnt", ".", "fuse", MS_NOSUID|MS_NODEV, "default_permissions,fd=5,rootmod"...) = -1 EPERM (Operation not permitted)
```

Interesting!  `"."` means the current directory.  So `fusermount` must already have been running on the mount point... somehow.  This trick can sometimes be used to access a directory, that you currently cannot access using its absolute path.

If we scroll up, we can see that `fusermount` did indeed change into this directory.  And it was also dancing with some UID-related (and GID-related) system calls.

```
[pid 30609] getuid()                    = 1000
[pid 30609] setfsuid(1000)              = 1000
[pid 30609] getgid()                    = 1000
[pid 30609] setfsgid(1000)              = 1000
[pid 30609] openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/fuse.conf", O_RDONLY) = 6
...
[pid 30609] lstat("/home/alan-sysop/mnt", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0775, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
[pid 30609] getuid()                    = 1000
[pid 30609] chdir("/home/alan-sysop/mnt") = 0
[pid 30609] lstat(".", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0775, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
[pid 30609] access(".", W_OK)           = 0
[pid 30609] getuid()                    = 1000
[pid 30609] setfsuid(1000)              = 1000
[pid 30609] setfsgid(1000)              = 1000
```

The UID results are "wrong" in the `strace` session.  We can see the UID dance part better in the `perf trace` session.  (I've removed the left-most columns for readability).

```
getuid(                                                               ) = 1000
setfsuid(uid: 1000                                                    ) = 0
getgid(                                                               ) = 1000
setfsgid(gid: 1000                                                    ) = 1000
openat(dfd: CWD, filename: 0xa428e2bc                                 ) = 6
    ...
close(fd: 6                                                           ) = 0
lstat(filename: 0xa63882a0, statbuf: 0x7ffe7bd4f6d0                   ) = 0
getuid(                                                               ) = 1000
chdir(filename: 0xa63882a0                                            ) = 0
lstat(filename: 0xa428eca5, statbuf: 0x7ffe7bd4f6d0                   ) = 0
access(filename: 0xa428eca5, mode: W                                  ) = 0
getuid(                                                               ) = 1000
setfsuid(                                                             ) = 1000
setfsgid(gid: 1000                                                    ) = 1000
getuid(                                                               ) = 1000
```

The `setfsuid()` calls are are in the `drop_privs()` and `restore_privs()` functions in [fusermount.c](https://github.com/libfuse/libfuse/blob/fuse-3.2.5/util/fusermount.c#L81).

The `chdir()` call is sneakily hidden in the function called `check_perm()`.

### Conclusion

Why does this work on NFS?  Answer: because NFS looks at the `fsuid` (and `fsgid`), which have been set to the non-root UID.

Why does this not work on FUSE, unless you have `allow_others`? Answer: because FUSE checks the "real" UID, and not the `fsuid`.